# Realm realmWithPath method in main bundle crashes on iOS

Tags: ios, realm

I do not use *.realm file in Document directory of app. I use it in main bundle directory.

When I call it:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"example" ofType:@"realm"];
RLMRealm *realm  = [RLMRealm realmWithPath:path];
```

It crashes and logs:

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: 'open() failed: Operation not permitted'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Realm file must be located in a directory to which you have write access in case you want to be able to update any data.
If you only intend to distribute a preset database with your app and access it read only, you must open it read only with [[RLMRealm realmWithPath:readOnly:error:]](http://realm.io/docs/cocoa/0.86.3/api/Classes/RLMRealm.html#//api/name/realmWithPath:readOnly:error:).

Comment: This answer is correct. More information in Realm's documentation: http://realm.io/docs/cocoa/latest/#other-realms